# Property ID error when trying to insert data into MongoDB through Python notebook

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to insert data into a MondoDB database through the following command written in Python - I'm using MongoDB's terminal to insert it:

db.sensores.insert(
I've tried editing it like this but now I'm getting a different error:

---

{
"timestamp": "2020-05-25T10:30:00Z",
"sensor_id": 1,
"location_id": 1,
"Ubicacion": "Valladolid",
"Coordenadas": "41.638597, 4.740186",
"Medidas": [
{
"tipo_medida":"Temperatura",
"valor":22.08,
"unidad":"ºC"
},
{
"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa",
"valor":34.92,
"unidad":"%"
}
]
},
{
"timestamp": "2020-05-28T11:30:00Z",
"sensor_id": 1,
"location_id": 2,
"Ubicacion": "Sevilla",
"Coordenadas": "37.409311, -5.949939",
"Medidas": [
{
"tipo_medida":"Temperatura",
"valor":21.12,
"unidad":"ºC"
},
{
"tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa",
"valor":37.7,
"unidad":"%"
}
]
},
{
"timestamp": "2020-05-28T1:30:00Z",
"sensor_id": 2,
"location_id": 2,
"Ubicacion":"Sevilla",
"Coordenadas": "37.409311, -5.949939",
"medidas":[
{
"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2",
"valor":2.102,
"unidad":"gCO2/m2"
},
{
"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico",
"valor":0.00272,
"unidad":"kWh/m2"
}
]
},
{
"timestamp": "2020-05-25T10:30:00Z",
"sensor_id": 2,
"location_id": 1,
"Ubicacion": "Valladolid",
"Coordenadas": "41.638597, 4.740186",
"medidas":[
{
"tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2",
"valor":1.626,
"unidad":"gCO2/m2"
},
{
"tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico",
"valor":0.00146,
"unidad":"kWh/m2"
}
]
}
]
)

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
"Parse error on line 19:
...%"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
          "times
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','"
```

I've tried going over all the brackets and punctuation but haven't been able to workout what I'm doing wrong. Anybody knows what the error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your JSON file.  Here is a valid JSON of your data.  Try it with this:

```
  [
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-25T10:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":1,
      "location_id":1,
      "Ubicacion":"Valladolid",
      "Coordenadas":"41.638597, 4.740186",
      "Medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Temperatura",
            "valor":22.08,
            "unidad":"ºC"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa",
            "valor":34.92,
            "unidad":"%"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-28T11:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":1,
      "location_id":2,
      "Ubicacion":"Sevilla",
      "Coordenadas":"37.409311, -5.949939",
      "Medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Temperatura",
            "valor":21.12,
            "unidad":"ºC"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa",
            "valor":37.7,
            "unidad":"%"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-28T1:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":2,
      "location_id":2,
      "Ubicacion":"Sevilla",
      "Coordenadas":"37.409311, -5.949939",
      "medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2",
            "valor":2.102,
            "unidad":"gCO2/m2"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico",
            "valor":0.00272,
            "unidad":"kWh/m2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-25T10:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":2,
      "location_id":1,
      "Ubicacion":"Valladolid",
      "Coordenadas":"41.638597, 4.740186",
      "medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2",
            "valor":1.626,
            "unidad":"gCO2/m2"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico",
            "valor":0.00146,
            "unidad":"kWh/m2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I've changed up a few things but now I'm getting a different error

Comment: You are still missing the array brackets.  Please figure out how to format JSON properly before you try to do anything with it. This site will tell you if your JSON is correct or not: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#.  Also, format your code in the OP properly.

Comment: That's the same tool I'm using and even changing after the array brackets it's giving me the same error

Comment: I fixed your JSON for you and replaced my answer with the correct JSON